# How does ASP.NET and IIS transform an <img src="localresource.jpg"> tag turn into an image file in the browser?

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, filestream, image

How does ASP.NET and IIS transform an `<img src="localresource.jpg">` tag turn into an image file in the browser?

I am assuming that it locates the file based on the path and renders a FileStream.  I don't see any handlers registered in web.config and my IIS6 configuration doesn't have anything about .jpg, .gif, .png, etc. extensions.

**Edit:**
Also, how can this process be customized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser sends a request for `/path/to/page/localresource.jpg`.

IIS finds the file, looks up the MIME type for `.jpg` in its default MIME-type mapping, and serves the file.
Neither ASP.Net nor the .Net framework are involved.  (unless you set them to be)

Comment: What exactly happens when it "serves the file"?

Comment: It reads it from disk, one chunk at a time, and sends the chunks down the network cable.

Comment: How do you customize this process?  e.g. If a file is not found, then the server looks in a different place or sends something else?  It's obviously an Http Request, but is it sent using an HttpResponse stream?  Can I plug into this with my handler?

Comment: You can configure IIS to send all requests through ASP.Net, then write an HttpModule.  Look into a routing framework.